# How to tell if ObjectProvider getObject() is returning a new or existing bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using a Spring `ObjectProvider` inside a `@RestController` to get a request–scoped bean.

Would it be possible to know if the returned bean instance has just been created or was already existing at the time of the `getObject()` call? I'd like to avoid tracking instance initialization if there's something already available.

The `getIfAvailable()` method seems to be more related to bean *type* existence in the factory rather than bean *instance* existence (I mean it would return `null` if the requested type doesn't exist in the factory, not if no instance has already been created).

Comment: Why not just use private field with default value true, and change it to false after first use?

Comment: @m1ld That's how I'm doing it, but I hoped for a better / native way.

Comment: Seems it's time to write feature request to spring core team. I have another problem ObjectProvider returns proxy of request scoped bean, when there is no request )